which node returns path to node, but not if I run in su - user -s /bin/bash -c 'which node'
When I run which node the command works, but if I run su - username -s /bin/bash -c 'which node' it returns empty. I have tried everything under the sun and can not get it to work.
I even tried su - username -s /bin/bash -c 'source ~/.bashrc ; which node'
root@vps-151c25b9:~# which node
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v20.18.0/bin/node
root@vps-151c25b9:~# su - username -s /bin/bash -c 'which node'
root@vps-151c25b9:~#
root@vps-151c25b9:~# su - username -s /bin/bash
username@vps-151c25b9:~$ which node
/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v20.18.0/bin/node
username@vps-151c25b9:~$

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't node show up when run with su ?
Edit: I just noticed, when I run
su - username -s /bin/bash -c "echo $PATH"

I get the path of root, not of the user username. Although root also has nvm & node and it doesn't find that either.
Edit 2: I tried single quotes , so it doesn't expand $PATH and got my correct path including nvm dir:
su username -c 'echo $PATH'

but when I try
su username -c 'source ~/.bashrc ; which node'

it still is empty.
Edit 3: I tried
su username -c '. ~/.profile ; which which'

(lol) and it returned /usr/bin/which, so the command works, just not for node.
Answer: I ran the following and it worked! I had to load NVM manually.
root@vps-151c25b9:~# su - username -c 'export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")" ; [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ; which node'
/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v20.18.0/bin/node

Thank you everyone for your help :)

When you run su - invidious -s /bin/bash -c "echo $PATH", root's shell will expand $PATH into root's path value before the command starts executing. Try su - invidious -s /bin/bash -c "printenv PATH" instead.

YEah thanks I did find an article saying such. I get correct path now. which which works, but which node does not :/

Please don't edit your answer into the question. Write an answer instead. After some delay you can accept the answer which will mark the question as answered.

Done ... I just assumed I would get in trouble for that rather than editing the OP.

I ran the following and it worked! I had to load NVM manually.
root@vps-151c25b9:~# su - username -c 'export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")" ; [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ; which node'
/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v20.18.0/bin/node

